# How to write International Movements in Australia Graduate Visa if I visited Schengen area?

Tags: visas, australia, applications

I'm applying for a graduate visa (subclass 485) in Australia. I'm currently stuck on:

> Part E: International Travel / Movements
>
> Have you travelled to any country other than Australia in the last 10 years?

I traveled to Europe last year with a tour. I got a Schengen visa. How should I write that in the form?

1. Should I write every country that I visited in Europe?
2. or should I just write Europe?

And how do I extend the form? Currently the form has only 5 rows. But I've traveled to other countries more than 5 times in the past 10 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I write that in the form?
>
> 1. Should I write every country that I visited in Europe?
> 2. or should I just write Europe?

Neither Europe nor the Schengen Area are countries.  You will need to list out every single country in the Schengen Area you have visited in the form.

> And how do I extend the form?

The final page in Australian immigration forms usually provides room for additional information (sample below).  Use this field to provide the additional information required, and reference the question number.

[image: Additional Information]